# What will I lose if US employer switches me to working for a foreign company?

Tags: employment, benefits, foreign

I'm a dual citizen having grown up in the US, but working and residing outside of US for 20 years. I have worked for my US-based employer for 10 years during which time I've been paid in the US with basically the same benefits as my US-based colleagues (although I don't have US health insurance). For legal reasons my employer now wants to pay me in the African country where I work. I have issues with this due to much higher taxation rates here and the presumed loss of my retirement benefits since these were all through my US employer's benefits program. I'm also wondering what else I will lose in terms of long-term protections/benefits things like disability, social security, workman's compensation? Is this correct? and is there any other things I will lose if my employer goes ahead with this?

Comment: "Is this correct?"  Looks like it to me.  "any other things I will lose"?  A stable currency.  (They're probably right about the legal reasons, and there are practical reasons too: US unemployment insurance is useless in Africa.)

Comment: Which African country? I'd say you stand to lose your contractual security as well, not many African countries have reasonably long traditions of the rule of Law.

Comment: Also, I read the first sentences as "for the last 10 years I betrayed the country I reside in" - because you have to pay taxes where you reside, so it sounds like the current setup was EXTREMELY illegal.

Comment: (+1) You ought to specify which country. It's possible you won't lose much: you said health insurance is not a factor, the law in the US differs a bit from state to state but, by and large, is not especially protective for workers, much of the benefits you mention depend on being a resident and could turn out not to be available when you need them.

Comment: One key issue is the salary: does your employer intend to keep paying the same gross salary than before? On the one hand, retirement and other benefits are part of the package and ought to count for something when setting the salary. On the other hand, a US salary is presumably higher than what you could get locally (especially since you have been evading taxes) so you made a good deal and the employer might be tempted to go back on that if they can.

Comment: At the end of the day, you don't really care about taxes *per se*, you care about your net income and what you can get your employer to pay you and there is no reason for the gross salary to stay the same.

Comment: @TomTom: Why do you have to pay taxes where you reside?  I've certainly paid quite a bit of tax to countries & US states where I DIDN'T reside.

Comment: The US (and one other place) are the only countries that require citizens to pay tax on worldwide income when not living there. Otherwise the rule is this: * You pay where you make the money (i.e. rental income in germany, taxed in germany, EVEN FROM A FRENCH LIVING IN SPAIN), * You pay your world income tax where you have tax residence, which is where you live 183 days per year or more * As american, you THEN pay income tax in the USA for all, but you can basically deduct the already paid taxes. That is the simple way. But "i live 10 years in country X" means you should have paid there.

Comment: As non US citizen residing in another country and not taking things like company constructions into account - you pay ZERO tax in income generated from US companies in the USA and all your taxes where you reside, And your business pretty much is where you are sitting in your office. Exceptions to this are possible, expensive and depending on your business (i.e. you can not declare a bakery is not making the money where the shop is, but you can run an offshore investment fund).

Comment: @TomTom: Perhaps my comment wasn't clear.  I mean ETHICALLY rather than legally (based on your use of the word "betrayed").  I would certainly have no ethical problem with not paying tax to California: I don't live there and don't benefit from any of their services (other than roads, which is covered by a gas tax).

Comment: If you set up a one-woman company, you are "exporting services" from Africa to the US. Are there any local tax benefits for remote workers or exporting companies? Maybe the tax rate won't be so bad if you look into incentives/exceptions. 

As for losing US benefits, the benefits you've already earned shouldn't be lost. It's just that no more US benefits will be earned from now on. 

You could simply ask your company an open-ended question, "can you mitigate my loss of benefits?"